# Get all property types - Umbraco 7

Tags: umbraco7, umbraco6, umbraco4

I'm trying to follow an example, but I think it was written for an older version so I am looking for the umbraco 7 equivalent to this:

```
List<PropertyType> types = PropertyType.GetAll().ToList();
```

Umbraco.Core.Models.PropertyType' does not contain a definition for 'GetAll' - this is the current error I am getting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use new services.
For working with DataTypes - DataTypeService

```
            var ds = ApplicationContext.Current.Services.DataTypeService;
            var dataTypes = ds.GetAllDataTypes();
```